# Why does this Django filter query return empty list?

Tags: django, django-taggit, django-filters

In my Vechicle table:

```
Vechicle.objects.all().first().tags.slugs()
<QuerySet ['car', 'awd']>
```

when I test it in python manage.py shell

```
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> q_objects = Q(tags__slug='car')
>>> q_objects &= Q(tags__slug='awd')
>>> q_objects
<Q: (AND: ('tags__slug', 'car'), ('tags__slug', 'awd'))>
>>> from partpicker.models import Vechicle 
>>> Vechicle .objects.all().filter(q_objects)
<QuerySet []>
```

EDIT:

Just to show that the normal queries work

```
>>> q_objects
<Q: (AND: ('tags__slug', 'car'), ('tags__slug', 'awd'))>
>>> Vechicle.objects.all().filter(tags__slug='car')
<QuerySet [<Vechicle: Vechicle object (2)>, <Vechicle: Vechicle object (27)>, <Vechicle: Vechicle object (29)>, <Vechicle: Vechicle object (30)>]>
>>> Vechicle.objects.all().filter(tags__slug='awd')
<QuerySet [<Vechicle: Vechicle object (29)>, <Vechicle: Vechicle object (30)>, <Vechicle: Vechicle object (31)>, <Vechicle: Vechicle object (32)>]>
>>> Vechicle.objects.all().filter(q_objects)
<QuerySet []>
```

this query should return object 29 and 30 correct?

I actually got it to work if I do it manually but with the q_object it still returns nothing:

```
>>> awd = Vechicle.objects.all().filter(tags__slug='awd')
>>> car = Vechicle.objects.all().filter(tags__slug='car')
>>> awd & car
<QuerySet [<Vechicle: Vechicle object (29)>, <Vechicle: Vechicle object (30)>]>
>>> q_objects = Q(tags__slug='awd') & Q(tags__slug='car')
>>> Vechicle.objects.all().filter(q_objects)
<QuerySet []>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks like `Q(tag__slug='car') & Q(tag__slug='awd')`, this means that the `slug` of the *same* tag should both be `Car` and `Slug`, which indeed does not work.

As you found out yourself, you need *multiple* [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) calls that will make joins.

You can however also use a trick with an *or* filter and counting. Indeed, you can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

data = ['car', 'awd']

Vehicle.objects.filter(tags__slug__in=data).alias(ntags=Count('tags')).filter(
    ntags=len(set(data))
)
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks the answer! 

What if I want to do something more complex?

(car or truck) and awd? or (car or truck) and (awd or 4x4)